# Ubuntu 12.10 stranger error on start up

Tags: 12.10, error-handling

When I start Ubuntu 12.10, after I enter the password, and my desktop show I get a "Send error report" Message ... every single time ?

I submit the error report and still nothing .... anyone have this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening to me as well until I ran:

`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`

That fixed me up.  Not sure what the problem was, but the bug was fixed.

Comment: Tnx that rally help me :-) !!!!